# Java multiplication quiz, how to loop if the answer is wrong

Tags: java, loops

I'm making a program in Java where the user is asked multiplication questions such as "What is 3*8". Currently, whether the user inputs the right or wrong answer, the program just asks a new question after it, and I'm wondering on how to make it so it keeps asking the same question until the user inputs the right answer:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.Random;

public class Multi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random number = new Random();

        while (true) {

            int nmb1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int nmb2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int multi = nmb1 * nmb2;

            int question = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is" + nmb1 + "*" + nmb2));

            if (question == multi) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, try again");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I think that I need to add something on the else part but I don't know what. I looked at similar questions but those didn't use the JOptionPane so it didn't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `do...while` block to repeat the same question/answer loop until the user types the correct answer:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random number = new Random();

        while (true) {

            int nmb1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int nmb2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int multi = nmb1 * nmb2;
            int question;

            // read the user's input ...
            do {
                question = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is" + nmb1 + "*" + nmb2));

                if (question != multi) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, try again");
                }
            }
            while (question != multi);
            // .. and repeat until the user types the correct answer

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
        }
    }
}
```